# Use of Object Mapper in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I am writing code for restaurant class the produces JSON in the given format during serialization

What are the best prectices to convert a json string using object Mapper

```
Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
restaurant = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Restaurant.class);
```

Comment: It should be `Restaurant restaurant = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Restaurant.class);` . `new Restaurant()` in first line is redundant.

Comment: The first line declares a `Restaurant` variable and assigns to it a new `Restaurant` object that is subsequently abandoned. The second line assigns to it another `Restaurant` object created from deserialising some JSON.

Comment: @khelwood what do I write in Restaurant class?

Comment: @khelwood and I am not able to understand the second line

Comment: Better Read  [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line creates a new Restaurant object. second line also creates a new Restaurant object but using a JSON string, you need Jackson library for this task. You don't need first line if your requirement is only to create an object.

lets say your Restaurant class looks like this.

```
class Restaurant {
   private String id;
   private String name;

   //getters and setters
}
```

and you have a JSON look likes this.

```
String json = "{ \"id\" : \"1\", \"name\" : \"My Restaurant\" }";
```

Then you can create Restaurant object using second line

```
Restaurant restaurant = objectMapper.readValue(json, Restaurant.class);
```

after that you can read json values from restaurant object.

```
System.out.println(restaurant.getName());
```

output:

```
My Restaurant
```

Comment: what do I write in Restaurant class?

Comment: and I am not able to understand the second line

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectMapper` will parse the JSON in `jsonString` to a `Restaurant` object (that's why you give it `Restaurant.class` as a parameter). It will then store the created object in the `restaurant` variable.